# Scheme list as an argument

Tags: list, scheme, racket

So in Scheme, if I make a list as an argument, how would I go about evaluating that list to itself in the same order?

Would I just write:
(define (function list)
   (list)

I don't really understand this.

Comment: What do you mean by "evaluating that list to itself"? And what do you mean by "same order"?

Comment: for example, like a function that would take a list of courses as an argument, and it would evaluate it to courses names in the same order as they were given

Comment: As the function takes the argument it is already a value... the list has already been evaluated, so there's nothing the function can do about the evaluation order. The only thing that might let you play with the evaluation order is either a list of thunk-functions, or a list of lazy-promises, where the function/promise value can be called/forced to evaluate the body. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you give a more concrete code example of how you would call the function, and what you would expect evaluation order to look like on that specific call?

Comment: @AlexKnauth I suspect it is as simple as `(define (foo list) list)` i.e. it returns the same list, as in "the list's elements in the same order", is the intended meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks an example.

Is this what you want:

```
(define (f . args) 
    args)
```

It can be used like this:

```
> (f 1 2 3)
(1 2 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list and a function which 'evaluates' elements of that list and you want to construct another list which is the result of calling that function on each element of the list then what you are doing is called *mapping the function over the list* and the function do do that is called `map`.  Given the following two definitions:

```
(define course-names '((1 "Exploding buckets 101")
                       (2 "Squirrel cooking 201")
                       (4 "Flamethrower maintenance 211")))

(define (course->name c)
  (let ((found (assq c course-names)))
    (if found (second found) "UNKNOWN SECRET COURSE")))
```

Then

```
> (map course->name '(1 2 3 4))
'("Exploding buckets 101"
  "Squirrel cooking 201"
  "UNKNOWN SECRET COURSE"
  "Flamethrower maintenance 211")
```

It's worth seeing how you can write things like `map`: here is one way:

```
(define (simple-map f l)
  (define (simple-map-loop tail accum)
    (if (null? tail)
        (reverse accum)
        (simple-map-loop (rest tail) (cons (f (first tail)) accum))))
  (simple-map-loop l '()))
```

Answer (score -1):

or:

```
(define (f lst)
  lst)
```

used as:

```
(f '(1 2 3))
;; '(1 2 3)
```